# Google App Engine Endpoints through proxy: ServerDoesNotExistError

Tags: google-app-engine, proxy, google-cloud-endpoints, devserver

i have the following setup for my webapp and restful service (two devservers):
- backend: google app engine (python) 1.8.0 using endpoints api (localhost:8080)
- frontend: angularjs, using yeoman+grunt (localhost:9000)
i want to keep these two seperate for testing purposes, however due to cross domain restrictions i tried to use a proxy on port 8050 to combine those two.
This seems to work fine for normal gae/webapp2 requests, but when trying to use my endpoints the gae-devserver throws "ServerDoesNotExistError: localhost:8050". I guess the endpoint server somehow needs to check the host for the discovery/explorer functionality.
Any ideas/workarounds would be highly appreciated.